# Laravel stopped working when changing HTTP to HTTPS and then back

Tags: laravel

I changed my Apache configuration to go to HTTPS. I used an `.htaccess` file to force redirection.

Then I had some issues with my Laravel site.

I looked at the history in Debian and reverted everything back.
1) `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` back to normal
2) `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` back to normal too
3) `/var/www/html/.env` back to normal too

Now when I connect with HTTP to the `/public` URL, it is going right, I see the page but now when I try to access any other URL, it returns a page not found.

I tried to also do a migrate refresh and reseeded the db but still nothing works...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I understand, while doing the htaccess file, I moved it to public folder and I didn't realise that there was already a file htaccess that laravel is using. So I had to find back to old version and install it again.